# How to match orange peel texture of wall paint?

Tags: drywall, painting, paint

The left hand side of this pic is a recently mudded patch, and the right side is the original paint job with orange peel.

When painting the patched part, how can I match the orange peel texture?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick up an aerosol can of the orange peel at the hardware store. You can get water as the solvent, where that stuff dries slowly and doesn't smell. You can get mineral spirits as the solvent, where that stuff dries quickly and smells.

The spray pattern on the can is adjustable. Practice on some cardboard to get the can set, to figure out the distance to hold it from your surface, and to figure out the time required to get a decent match.

Comment: Possibly pick up a second can, just in case testing takes up too much of the first can.

Comment: You can also try using a very thick primer, like Zinsser 123.